# How many grams of almonds are in a tsp of almond extract?

Tags: almonds, ratio, extracts, concentration

How many grams of almonds are in a tsp of almond extract?  Looking for equivalency or concentration rations for almonds to almond extract.

Comment: You can't really substitute one for the other but recipes usually ask for about 10 to 15 almonds to make about 1/2 cup of extract.

Comment: @Halhex- 1/2 cup?! 1 tsp of almond extract is a lot. Did you mean 1/2 tsp?